# Mysql database replication with geo-distributed servers

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication, multi-master, master-master-replication

I am just a developer, who doesn't have deep knowledge in DBA. So need experts suggestions in this.
I have two  offline databases in two cities, I want to make a synchronization between two databases using a third database which will be stay alway online in a live server.

My problem is like this,
**Location A** database is in New York.
**Location B** database is in Canada. 
And they are in local machine, so no connection between them. Now I need to show the changes of **Location A**'s to **Location B** and **Location B**'s to **Location A**. Yeah this can be solve by MASTER-MASTER replication. Also i have found a way to solve *autoincrement indexes* issue, by separating index numbers in different servers.

But I need another live **server C** where **Location A**'s and **Location B**'s change will reflect. So some users need not to access Location A or Location B for looking into changes. I do not also want's to use RING replication. because if one goes down then rest of the RING will be broken.

In summery I want to make the replication like this

[image]

Need help about replication process.

Thanks in advance,

Nixon

Comment: What version are you running?  Does it have "multi-source" replication?

Comment: it's 5.7. I am still developing the solutions. So I'm open for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that could work is a Galera cluster with one node in read-only mode. (See e.g. [here](http://galeracluster.com/2015/07/geo-distributed-database-clusters-with-galera/) for info about geo-distributed Galera cluster.) Galera cluster is a (virtually) synchronous multi-master solution. [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-is-mariadb-galera-cluster/) and [Percona](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/intro.html) provide this technology, as does [Galera themselves](http://galeracluster.com/downloads/). There is one problem: Since you would be writing to more than one node, there is a higher likelihood of experiencing deadlocks / certification failures, including on commit. (See [this article](https://ghostaldev.com/2016/05/22/galera-gotcha-mysql-users/) for an explanation.) However, this is something your application could handle if you take care when developing it.

Be sure to review the [Galera cluster limitations](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/limitations.html) before you decide on this technology. Some of the most notable requirements are: A Linux OS, it only supports the InnoDB storage engine, and all tables must have an explicit primary key.

[MySQL Group Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-requirements.html) is a similar technology, but this wouldn't be suitable for geo-distributed database nodes as in your use-case.

Comment: Even writing to one node, you can get deadlocks.  The only difference is that you must check for errors also on `COMMIT`.  InnoDB and mandatory PK are not big constraints.  Galera has a way to handle "Critical read".  [_Another discussion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera).